# Как обновить исполнительный файл в qt c++ посредством перезапуска программы

Tags: c++, qt, update

вот предоставляю код

```
void MainWindow::restartLauncher()
{
    QString appDirPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
    QString newLauncherPath = appDirPath + "/new_mainwindow.exe";
    QString currentLauncherPath = appDirPath + "/mainwindow.exe";

    qApp->quit();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    QCoreApplication::exit(); 

    QFile file("mainwindow.exe");
    file.remove();

    if (QFile::rename(newLauncherPath, currentLauncherPath))
    {
        QProcess::startDetached(currentLauncherPath);
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "Failed to replace launcher file. Please check the files.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Представлен исходный код программы `mainwindow.exe`? Программа пытается удалить сама себя? Это невозможно. Только bat-файлы умеют удалять сами себя. Вы можете в своем коде генерировать временный bat-файл, который удалит вашу программу, а потом запустит новую программу и удалит себя.

Comment: просто я думал что можно закрыть программу что бы во время перезапуска она заменила исполнительнй файл и открылась, но видимо я не настолько умный, спасибо за ответ, благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Принцип скорее должен быть такой:

1. Программа на запуске удаляет старый файл если такой имеется
2. Если нужно обновить исполняемый файл:

   1. Программа переименовывает текущий файл в старый
   2. Программа скачивает и запускает новый файл

Т.е. у вас будет что-то в духе:

```
QString appDirPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
QString oldLauncherPath = appDirPath + "/old_mainwindow.exe";
QString currentLauncherPath = appDirPath + "/mainwindow.exe";

QFile::remove(oldLauncherPath); //На самом деле должна быть на старте программы

if (/*Проверяем необходимость обновления*/) {
    if (QFile::rename(currentLauncherPath, oldLauncherPath)) {
        //Здесь мы получаем новый mainwindow.exe
        //...
        QProcess::startDetached(currentLauncherPath);
        //Завершаем программу
    } 
}
```

Перед осуществлением п. 1 желательно убедиться, что старый процесс завершён.